# jQueryUI autocomplete suggestions showing up outside input field

Tags: django, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have set up an autocomplete form with jQueryUi in a Django project.

Autocomplete is working fine. Problem is, suggestions are not displayed under my form but on the right side of the screen.

[image: My screenshot]

I need the suggestion to appear just under my search field as it should and to display only the 10 first products that matches my search.

My HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
 <input id="prod" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="query" placeholder="">
</div>
```

My AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $("#prod").autocomplete({     
     source: "/finder/search_auto",
     select: function (event, ui) { 
        AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
      },
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
    var selectedObj = ui.item;
  }
```

My views.py:

```
$(function() {
    $("#prod").autocomplete({     
     source: "/finder/search_auto",
     select: function (event, ui) { 
        AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
      },
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });$( "#prod" ).autocomplete({
    position: { my : "right top", at: "right bottom" }
    });

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
    var selectedObj = ui.item;
  }
```

Comment: Did you include JqueryUI CSS?

Comment: I put:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update it with last version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

That should do the trick.